# I'm getting this error while installing any node modules. eg: This error occur while installing MUI Toolpad

Tags: npm-install, toolpad

`npx create-toolpad-app@latest my-toolpad-app` using this command to install MUI Toolpad but getting this error

```
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! network request to https://registry.npmjs.org/create-toolpad-app failed, reason: connect ETIMEDOUT 2606:4700:9763:80e2:e442:5cb:6810:23:443
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

> using node version 18.17.0

I have tried 2 different command suggested by MUI

> npx create-toolpad-app dog-app

> npx create-toolpad-app@latest my-toolpad-app

Comment: It looks like connectivity problems with npm unrelated to Toolpad. Do you have trouble installing other node modules? e.g. does running `npx cowsay hello` work?

Comment: Yes, you're right this problem doesn't related with Toolpad. But do you have any solution for this ? because npx cowsay hello , or any other installing node modules only works if i install them after restarting my computer or freshly start my computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your previous responses, check if you've accidentally installed Node multiple times or with different paths. This might cause this problem.

Comment: I realized that I have two different users, and it appears that another user had installed Node.js in a different directory. I believe this could be the reason causing the problem I'm experiencing. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have change the proxy when the time you were installing the

npx create-toolpad-app dog-app

please check your connectivity check whether you are using a VPN or have you change the IP address from internet settings. Bcz you need to have a active internet connection I have faced these issues earlier

Comment: I haven't made any changes to the proxy settings, and I am not using a VPN. Based on my assessment, it seems that the issue is not related to my internet connection.